# two elements in a same function jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I trigger an event that two html elements can trigger the event. **rules:
 (the 1st element cannot trigger an event if the 2nd element is false. both are true in order to trigger the event)**

> the #select is select tag is a first element with the "option" Option 2
>  the #test5 is input radio type tag is the second element

here is my code

```
$("#select").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "Option 2") {
    if($("#test5").click() == true) {
      alert("wawi");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: `.click()` doesn't return a boolean. If you want to know if a checkbox or radio button is checked, use `.is(":checked")`.

Comment: How about you try this. `$('#test5').on('click or change or the event you want',function(){  if ($(#select).val() === "Option 2")alert("wawi");});`

Comment: if `#test5` is radio box you need to check if it is selected or not

Comment: You have an extra `});` line

Comment: When you are change the select , how can you click on radio `#test5`

Comment: not sure what u try to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to tell if a checkbox or radio button is checked is:

```
if ($("#test5").is(":checked"))
```

Other than that, I think your code should work.

```js
$("#select").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "Option 2") {
    if ($("#test5").is(":checked")) {
      alert("wawi");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="r" id="test1"> 1
<input type="radio" name="r" id="test2"> 2
<input type="radio" name="r" id="test3"> 3
<input type="radio" name="r" id="test4"> 4
<input type="radio" name="r" id="test5"> 5
<br>
<select id="select">
<option value="Option 1">1</option>
<option value="Option 2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering  but doesnt work. ("#select,").on("change" , function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Option 2") {
      if ($("#test5").is(":checked")) {
    alert("wawi");
}
 
 }
 });
 
});    //is this the code you expecting?

Comment: I added a code snippet, it works. Check box 5, then change the select to `2`, and you get the alert.

Comment: Thanks broo!. it really helped